# Select vazio sem aparecer na lista

Tags: html, html5, html-select

tudo bom?

Estou com algumas duvidas sobre a tag select do HTML. Teria como colocar o ele sem opção pre-selecionada sem que o mesmo apareça na lista? todos os exemplos que encontrei sempre há pelo menos um item na lista aparecendo, ou  "selecione uma opção" e esse mostra o essa mensagem na lista, teria como deixar vazio sem que apareça na lista?

[Exemplo do w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: crie um item vazio no lugar de "selecione uma opção", isso não resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você deixar uma opção em branco ele fica vazio

Podemos ver utilizando o próprio exemplo do w3schools

A diretiva `disabled` impede que você selecione o vazio e a `selected` deixa pré selecionado ele

```html
<select>
  <option value="" data-default disabled selected></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mais ou menos, só tem esse tipo de abordagem?

Comment: @AndreFirmo é a forma que eu conheço.